# Why is the & 1 and + '0' is needed to display the binary number?

Tags: c, binary, char, shift, bitwise-and

I got this code here to print the binary of a decimal, if I ran this function with argument as 3, it would print 0000 0011, which is right, I understand that >> will shift the binary to the right 7 to 0 to display the binary, but I do not understand the purpose of the code: & 1 and + 0, can someone tell me what are those for?

```
void gal_print(gal8 a)
{
    int i = 8;
    while (i--)
       // printf("%d", i);
        putchar((a >> i & 1) + '0');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression with the bitwise operator `&` (bitwise AND operator)

```
a >> i & 1
```

is used to extract the right most bit of the number. So the result value of the expression will be either `0` or `1`.

For example

```
00000011 // 3
&
00000001 // 1
========
00000001 // 1
```

or

```
00000010 // 2
&
00000001 // 1
========
00000000 // 0
```

As there is used the function `putchar` then this integer value is required to be converted to character.

```
putchar((a >> i & 1) + '0');
```

That is `'0' + 0` gives the character `'0'` and `'0' + 1` gives the character `'1'`.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does not have to ... (no `&`, no + `'0'`)

```
void gal_print(unsigned char a)
{
    int i = CHAR_BIT;
    while (i--)
    {
        if(((unsigned char)(((a >> i) << (CHAR_BIT - 1))) >> (CHAR_BIT - 1)))
        {
            putchar('1');
        }
        else
        {
            putchar('0');
        }
    }

}
```